# Ec-cube 4.2.2 installation with Xampp 8.2.4

Tags: xampp

when I try to install ec-cube using http://localhost/ec-cube/ URL, I got the error as follows.

```
Warning: openssl_pkey_export(): Cannot get key from parameter 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\app\Plugin\Api42\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ApiCompilerPass.php on line 111

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: openssl_pkey_get_details(): Argument #1 ($key) must be of type OpenSSLAsymmetricKey, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\app\Plugin\Api42\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ApiCompilerPass.php:113 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\app\Plugin\Api42\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ApiCompilerPass.php(113): openssl_pkey_get_details(false) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\app\Plugin\Api42\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ApiCompilerPass.php(90): Plugin\Api42\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ApiCompilerPass->generateKeys('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\app\Plugin\Api42\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ApiCompilerPass.php(33): Plugin\Api42\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ApiCompilerPass->configureKeyPair(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Compiler\Compiler.php(82): Plugin\Api42\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ApiCompilerPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\ContainerBuilder.php(757): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder)) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php(546): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php(787): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php(190): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot() #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\index.php(83): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #9 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ec-cube\app\Plugin\Api42\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ApiCompilerPass.php on line 113
```

How to rectify this??

I tried

1. Enable `" ; extension=openssl" in php.ini . → "extension=openssl"`.
2. Changed `"SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF “C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf”” to “SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF “C:/xampp/apache/conf/openssl.cnf”” in httpd- xampp.conf` .